# Why does react native only allows .png as app icon?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a expo managed react native project.
I have put an icon.jpg file in the assets folder and added the following line in app.json:

```
"icon": "./assets/icon.jpg",
```

Now when I run the project it shows the error:

> Field: icon - field 'icon' should point to .png image but the file at './assets/icon.jpg' has type jpg.

I  checked the expo documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/

It says that

> Use png files.
> What is the reason that expo only allows .png file for setting app icon and splash screen?